# dhcpcd.serve failed after recent updates

Tags: systemd, dhcpcd

### My System

Raspberry Pi 3B running RaspberryPi OS Bullseye 32 bit. Even though it has a desktop I mainly use it as a server, running Pihole inside a docker container.

### Probable Cause

After the most recent system updates that updated systemd and quite a few other things (but not dhcpcd) and a reboot, dhcpcd.service failed to start.

```
● dhcpcd.service - DHCP Client Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:dhcpcd(8)
```

### Diagnosis

```
ip a && ip r
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:ac:eb:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.146/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 7087sec preferred_lft 7087sec
    inet6 2600:4040:4448:1800:2c23:e13e:29e7:d26a/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86290sec preferred_lft 14290sec
    inet6 fe80::b824:f9d:715:ce85/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 66:ed:0c:59:93:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr b8:27:eb:f9:be:df
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0f:0f:14:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-9691d3b33dc8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:69:20:05:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-9691d3b33dc8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:69ff:fe20:526/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: vethdfd065d@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-9691d3b33dc8 state UP group default 
    link/ether 42:21:48:23:cf:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::4021:48ff:fe23:cfa8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vethec71e9f@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-9691d3b33dc8 state UP group default 
    link/ether c6:f9:14:1a:26:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::c4f9:14ff:fe1a:26bf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-9691d3b33dc8 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.146 metric 100
```

This shows `eth0` is assigned `192.168.0.146` out of the dynamic IP address range instead of the static IP address `192.168.0.65`.

### The Problem

The Pi is not getting the static IP address set in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface eth0
#inform 192.168.0.65
static ip_address=192.168.0.65/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
```

Instead the Pi gets a different IP address assigned by the home router. This breaks remote access.

Note, `192.168.0.65` is outside the range of the IP addresses dynamically assigned by the home router. It was working fine until the update.

### A Workaround

First, I ran the command:

```
sudo dhcpcd -g
```

Later I found running the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service
```

Both the commands assign the correct IP address.

### The Question

How do I troubleshoot what is causing the problem with dhcpcd at reboot so that I don't have to locally login after each reboot and restart the service?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry @Milliways I ran `ip addr show` and it showed `192.168.0.146/24` assigned to `eth0`. I can replicate the problem by enabling network manager and  edit my question.

Comment: You CAN enable Network Manager BUT this has to be done manually (through raspi-config) and if you enable it it will definitely BREAK dhcpcd. I actually use both (not on the same machine) and you need to make a number of other changes to use NM on an existing OS.

Comment: @Milliways I have added the information you wanted.

Comment: @Milliways enabling of Network Manager was unintentional on my part. At some point I may want to enable it and set up static IP through it. But that is another question. :D

Comment: For future reference `systemctl status dhcpcd` & `systemctl status NetworkManager` will show status. What you listed in your question is what I see on my Pi running NM but there can be other causes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **guess**... I've not seen this in any sort of an "official notice", but I recall reading recently that our friends in *"The Organization"* have finally pulled the plug on `dhcpcd`, and replaced it with `Network Manager`. This [change was originally announced here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/the-latest-update-to-raspberry-pi-os/). I had assumed they would postpone this change until release of `bookworm`, but apparently the *powers-that-be* decided to go ahead.

If you want to stick with `dhcpcd` for the time being, I would advise ***disabling*** network manager; don't know exactly how `systemd` will handle having both `dhcpcd` and `network manager` enabled, but suspect this would be done *awkwardly*.

Comment: When I looked at the `unattended-upgrade` logs I noticed starting of NetworkManager.service was pending. It was started at reboot. I didn't connect the dots. Thanks for the answer. It was a good guess. `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service` and a reboot fixed the problem,

Comment: DO NOT keep repeating these unfounded rumours. Try rereading the Raspberry Pi Ltd. announcement which mentioned this. A fresh install DOES NOT use Network Manager (although users CAN select it as an option).

Comment: OK... do something for me, Milliways: DO NOT continue to be an asshole.